# Sorting graphs numerically instead of alphabetically

Tags: graph, stata

I have created a graph in Stata and I want to sort the items numerically. I want the countries with the greatest subnational revenue to be at the top. (Canada would be at the top if sorted numerically.)

At the moment, I can only get the items to sort alphabetically. As you can see, Afghanistan is at the top

[image]

I've uploaded the graph file (.gph) to google drive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DMlE30SsY-L6v8ulCE2OOiTEeZA00DKk/view?usp=sharing

Please take a look and let me know how I might sort my graph items numerically.

Comment: Your question could be answered -- good -- but for similar questions in future posting the command used -- here `graph hbar (max) SubnationalRevenue, over(Dem) over(Country) asy`  -- would have been much simpler and more direct than posting a `.gph` file elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep in 45/60
separate price, by(foreign) veryshortlabel
graph hbar price0 price1, over(make, sort(price) descending) yvaroptions(relabel(1 "Domestic"  2"Foreign")) nofill
```

[image: sort_example]